# Undefined property error when trying to use a relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following relation between a post and it's comments :

In the Post model :

```
public function comments()
    {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id'); 
    }
```

In the Comment model :

```
public function posts()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'id');   // id is the primary key in posts table
    }
```

The posts are returning without any issue in the below foreach loop, but whenever I try to use the relationship to bring the comments, I see the below error :

Foreach :

```
@foreach($topans as $topanswer)

           <p> {{$topanswer->body}} </p>

           <br>
   @if(!empty($topanswer->comments))
       @foreach($topans->comments as $topanscom)

            <p>{{$topanscom->comment}} </p>

       @endforeach
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Error :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$comments (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\sharp\resources\views\showPost.blade.php)
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to pull the entire collection's worth of answers in your *inner* foreach loop.  The top level collection (`$topans`) is a collection of **topanswers**, and does not have a field `comments` since it is a collection.

Try to pull the second level `topanswer`'s comments in that inner foreach loop:

```
@foreach($topanswer->comments as $topanscom)
```

Also, just as a side note, I think you've fallen into the trap of naming -- it might help to use a little bit more descriptive or different names, it would help you get out of trouble :)

Comment: I get into trouble in the same way quite a bit with inner loops like that.  It helps a lot to change the name of the second set of variables to something easily recognizable as different.  Maybe `$innerAnswer` or `secondaryAnswer`... :)

Comment: Sure, will try to adjust my variable names a little bit.